# SSD Wear Leveling . . . how/where are the LDA remaps kept?

Tags: wear-leveling

On one level I get both static and dynamic wear leveling.  Put some smarts in there to move the blocks around.

However, what none of the descriptions I've seen explain is how that remapping information is saved?

All these usage counts and where you moved the block too . . . that info needs to be kept "someplace" and seems to me "that place" is also subject to wear and would itself break down.

It seems to me we have robbed Peter to pay Paul.  Is there some second kind of "rugged memory" that is in SSD devices?

Comment: I would imagine you could use a more expensive and/or slower memory that has much greater or unlimited write endurance, since you only need a little bit. FRAM comes to mind, but that might be *too* expensive.

Comment: Multi-level cells can be used as SLC cells, which will give them a longer life.

Comment: The mapping storage can also use wear leveling. There is no reason why main data blocks use wear leveling but auxiliary metadata doesn't.

Comment: It used to be the case that these "reserved pages" often weren't wear-leveled. But I think today they are brought under some algorithm that balances well. However, the algorithm for them is likely not identical to that for data pages/bytes, as they are continually updated, which suggests different ways for storing and observing their data by not using fixed locations. It's slower. But at least it works. (If I get time, I may explain a method I've used. But right now I'm pretty busy elsewhere.)